# Return on investment in international development projects

Tags: data-request, government, finance, bank

The World Bank has [ratings](http://ieg.worldbankgroup.org/ratings) for its development projects. The dataset is comprehensive, but crucial details, like return on investment, are missing.

What are other sources of data on projects in international development, such as power plants, roads, investments in equipment, and so on? Maybe some governments disclose information about their projects? Or organizations besides the World Bank?

Return on investment, IRR, and other financial metrics would be extremely appreciated, but I would also be glad to have any related information on large development projects.

Answer (score 4):

great question.

The first thing to note is that the IEG database that you're referencing is only one of several that the World Bank provides. You might want to also check out the Bank's projects portal: http://www.worldbank.org/projects. In particular, check out specific country pages for a lot of good details, as well as many project documents (in pdf) for most projects.

In addition, you might want to check out this platform that tracks many types of development financing (aid, private foundations, remittance flows, etc.): aiddata.org

More and more organizations in international development are also providing data on their own projects. A few examples:

- DfID (UK): http://devtracker.dfid.gov.uk/
- AfDB's project portfolio
- AsDB: adb[dot]org[forwardslash]projects

Many countries are now also publishing their own aid information. Just a handful here:

- Haiti's MGAE
- Nepal aid management system
- Timor aid management system
- Bangladesh aid information system
- Afghanistan DAD system

More and more organizations and countries are reporting actual deliverables from these investments, but that information is more scattered and difficult to synthesize. RoI itself is hard to measure, as there's no clear indication of how you might track that.

Comment: Thank you. Fischer, "Growth, Macroeconomics, and Development," reports ROI for private/public projects from Kaufmann (1991) who used closed WB data. So, some ROI data at least exists :)